# Profile report to PDF PANDAS_PROFILING

Tags: python, pandas, pdf, profiling, pandas-profiling

Hi I'm doing some EDA and I'm using pandas_profiling I would like to have something similar but in a pdf format, there is something like that a code a resource a library?
There is a way to make it better the profiling? I would like some help with this please

This is my code:

```
profile = ProfileReport(df, title="Raw Dataset Analysis", explorative=True)
profile.to_file("report.html")
```